# Wait until Boolean is True in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have cells that have buttons that trigger the downloading of their respective PDF from online. I want it so that only one download can occur at a time, and the other ones (if their button is clicked) wait for it to finish.

I cannot use any sort of queue, because the queue operation calls the download methods but does not wait for them to complete before moving on.

Is there any way that I can only move on once the did finish download function says that it is ready by passing a boolean or something? I am pretty lost here so any direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up a tutorial on GCD. You'll want to use a dispatch semaphore.

Comment: Watch. This. Video. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/

Comment: you need to use dispatch_semaphore for and signal when you finish one process from queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot use any sort of queue, because the queue operation calls the download methods but does not wait for them to complete before moving on.

This can be accomplished using NSOperation Queues. The key is that your download tasks have to be async `NSOperation` subclasses where you mark the operation as finished when the download finishes. More importantly, these operations should be queued on a serial queue. Then, operations will be executed only one at a time in FIFO order.

However, it takes a bit of boilerplate to get NSOperations setup this way. Another good way to do it is using Dispatch Groups.

```
// A serial queue ensures only one operation is executed at a time, FIFO
let downloadsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.youapp.pdfdownloadsqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
let downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()

func queueDownload(from url: NSURL) {
    // Register this download task with the group
    dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)

    // Async dispatch the download task to our serial queue,
    // so that it returns control back without blocking the main thread
    dispatch_async(downloadsQueue) {
        downloadPDF(with: url) { (pdf, error) in
            // handle PDF data / error
            // { .. }

            // leave the dispatch group in the completion method,
            // notifying the group that this task is finished
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)
        }
    }
}

func downloadPDF(with url: NSURL, completion: (pdf: NSData?, error: ErrorType?) -> ()) {
    // make network request
    // call completion with PDF data or error when the download request returns
}
```